# how do I convert this query in django ORM

Tags: postgresql, orm

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    ( 
        SELECT
            T_JOB_TASK.ID
            , T_JOB_TASK.JOB_DETAIL_ID
            , T_JOB_DETAIL.JOB_ID
            , ( 
                SELECT
                    T_INVOICE.ISSUE_FLAG 
                FROM
                    T_CASE 
                    INNER JOIN T_JOB 
                        ON T_JOB.ID = T_CASE.JOB_ID 
                    INNER JOIN T_CASE_REPORT_RELATION 
                        ON T_CASE_REPORT_RELATION.CASE_ID = T_CASE.ID 
                    INNER JOIN T_INVOICE 
                        ON T_INVOICE.ID = T_CASE_REPORT_RELATION.INVOICE_ID 
                WHERE
                    T_CASE.JOB_ID = T_JOB_DETAIL.JOB_ID
            ) AS INVOICE_ISSUE_FLAG
            , ( 
                SELECT
                    BOOL_OR(T_INVOICE_DATA_EXPORT_RESULT.INVOICE_ISSUE_FLAG) 
                FROM
                    T_INVOICE_DATA_EXPORT_RESULT_DETAIL 
                    INNER JOIN T_INVOICE_DATA_EXPORT_RESULT 
                        ON T_INVOICE_DATA_EXPORT_RESULT.ID =    T_INVOICE_DATA_EXPORT_RESULT_DETAIL.INVOICE_DATA_EXPORT_RESULT_ID
                WHERE
                    T_INVOICE_DATA_EXPORT_RESULT_DETAIL.JOB_ID = T_JOB_DETAIL.JOB_ID
            ) AS INVOICE_ISSUE_FLAG2 
        FROM
            T_JOB_TASK 
            INNER JOIN T_JOB_DETAIL 
                ON T_JOB_DETAIL.ID = T_JOB_TASK.ID 
        WHERE
            T_JOB_TASK.INSPECTION_FLAG = TRUE
    ) TMP 
WHERE
    NOT ( 
        COALESCE(INVOICE_ISSUE_FLAG, FALSE) 
        OR COALESCE(INVOICE_ISSUE_FLAG2, FALSE)
    );
```

Here's my django API code:

```
invoice_issue_flag_subquery = Invoice.objects.filter(
            case_report_invoice__case__job__id=OuterRef("job_detail__job_id")
        ).values("issue_flag")[:1]

        invoice_issue_flag2_subquery = (
            InvoiceDataExportResult.objects.filter(
                invoicedataexportresultdetail__job_id=OuterRef("job_detail__job_id")
            )
            .annotate(invoice_issue_flag2=Coalesce(BooleanField(), Value(False)))
            .values("invoice_issue_flag")[:1]
        )

        job_subquery = (
            JobTask.objects.annotate(
                issue_flag=Subquery(invoice_issue_flag_subquery),
                invoice_issue_flag=Subquery(invoice_issue_flag2_subquery),
            )
            .filter(inspection_flag=True)
            .filter(Q(issue_flag=True) | Q(invoice_issue_flag=True)),
        )

        print("jq: ", list(job_subquery))
        job_detail_list = []
        job_subquery = list(job_subquery)
        for job_qry in job_subquery:
            # print("-> ", job_qry)
            for x in job_qry:
                print("-->>", x.job_detail.id)
                job_detail_list.append(x.job_detail.id)
            # pass
            # print("job qry", job_qry.job_detail)
        queryset = JobDetail.objects.filter(
            # job_subquery.filter(invoice_issue_flag=True),
            id__in=job_detail_list,
        )
```

But this is returning 9 rows of data, but the query is returning 14 rows of data. While I compare this code generates a different query than the query I actually wanted to be executed